# PHP, XPath and SimpleXML - XPath not working

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following PHP and XML:

```
$XML = <<<XML
<items>
    <item id="12">
        <name>Item A</name>
    </item>
    <item id="34">
        <name>Item B</name>
    </item>
    <item id="56">
        <name>Item C</name>
  </item>
</items>
XML;


$simpleXmlEle = new SimpleXMLElement($XML);

print_r($simpleXmlEle->xpath('./item[1]'));
print "- - - - - - -\n";
print_r($simpleXmlEle->xpath('./item[2][@id]'));
print "- - - - - - -\n";
print_r($simpleXmlEle->xpath('./item[1]/name'));
```

I am able to access the ID like this

```
$simpleXmlEle->items->item[0]['id']
```

As it is a dynamic application the xpath is provided at runtime as a string so I believe I should use xpath.

The above PHP produces:

PHP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                )

            [name] => Item A
        )

)
- - - - - - -
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 34
                )

            [name] => Item B
        )

)
- - - - - - -
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

I understand the 1st output, but inside the 2nd output the whole element is being returned instead of just the attribute. 
**1) Any ideas why?**

Also the last item is empty
**2)why is this and what would be the right xpath?**

I am aiming for 2nd and 3rd output as: 34 (value of id attribute of 2nd element) Item A (just name of 1st element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below:

```
// name only
$name = $simpleXmlEle->xpath("./item[1]/name");
echo $name[0], PHP_EOL;

// id only
$id = $simpleXmlEle->xpath("./item[2]/@id");
echo $id[0], PHP_EOL;
```

Prints:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Item A ) )
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 34 ) ) )
```

Make sure you **DO NOT** do:

```
print_r($objSimpleXML->xpath("//item[1]/name"));
```

According to the documentation // returns ALL elements with this name, so if there is an item element on a deeper level then its value is returned too which is not be desired.

hope that helps